# Mysql check previews row with out ID column

Tags: mysql, sql

This table doesn't not have a ID column. That's the reason I don't know how to compare it.

It need to check the previews rows with the fields `Keyword` and `Day` they need to be the same. If there is no previews row then put 1 in `Ranking` in it.
When there is a previews row then get previews `Ranking` and make it `Ranking+1` and update the field `Ranking`.

Start Table

```
Keyword    Asin       Day   Ranking
test red  28923    1-1-2018  
test red  98254    1-1-2018  
test red  79845    1-1-2018  
test green 154684  1-1-2018  
test red  28923    2-1-2018  
test red  98254    2-1-2018  
test red  79845    2-1-2018  
test green 154684  2-1-2018
```

Result Table

```
Keyword    Asin       Day   Ranking
test red  88923    1-1-2018  1
test red  98254    1-1-2018  2
test red  79845    1-1-2018  3
test green 154684  1-1-2018  1
test red  88923    2-1-2018  1
test red  98254    2-1-2018  2
test red  79845    2-1-2018  3
test green 154684  2-1-2018  1
```

I think i need a join and nested query. I'm not sure maybe i need to create 
 virtual `ID` like this:

```
SET @ID=0;


Select *
FROM
SELECT @ID:=@ID+1 AS ranking, Keyword, Asin, Day, Ranking
  FROM RankingT
;
```

Edit:  Change `Asin` numbers

Answer (score 0):

Note:  Your specified ranking appears to depend on the original order of the table.  But that doesn't make sense because tables represent *unordered* sets.

The following answer provides a solution, but the ranking is slightly different.  If you want one based on your ordering, then you need a column that specifies the ordering (and this can be plugged into the expression where `asin` is).

You can do this with a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.keyword = t.keyword and t2.day = t.day and
              t2.asin <= t.asin
       ) as ranking
from t;
```

That said, this will work fine on smallish data sets -- especially if you have an index on `t(keyword, day, asin)`.  For larger data sets, variables might be more efficient.

Comment: Asin are random numbers you can't use it in the `WHERE` statement

Comment: @FT . . . Your comment makes no sense in the context of the question.  According to the question, `asin` is a column in the table.

Comment: look at the data you can't use <=

Comment: @FT . . . I've clarified the answer.